# Missing wobbly windows effect

Tags: nvidia, compiz, 12.10

Just installed 12.10 then CCSM but there is no option for wobbly windows.

Any one got this working or know a plug-in? (I am using Nvidia graphics).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fixed this. It is now included in the extra plugins.

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

Comment: This also works in 13.04 :D

Comment: ..in 13.10 also and probably in any future version :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need Compiz... And you will have to enable wobbly windows manually in Compiz panel...